# How can I read output of select statement and assign it to various parameters in batchfile in loop

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, scripting, sqlcmd

I have a scenario where I need to pass the result of select statement to batch script and then generate another file with the values.

SQL Query:

```
Select SrcName, TrgName from dbo.t_src_trg_ref where Loadstatus='Assinged'
```

O/P for this query be like:

```
SrcName | TrgName
src1    |    trg1
src2    |    trg2
src3    |    trg3
```

And so on

Batch script should read this output and generate a text file for each row in a loop, content of the file should be like:

```
file1.txt 
$$src=src1
$$trg=trg1

file2.txt
$$src=src2
$$trg=trg2

file3.txt
$$src=src3
$$trg=trg3
```

And so on.

Any help in this regard, I am new to batch scripting and finding it very difficult to develop batch script for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why can't you create the files in SQL?

Comment: Don't have execute permission on extended stored procs in SQL server. That's why want to do this in Batch Script :(

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [SQL cursor](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/cursor.aspx) then within the cursor loop codes, using SQL BCP command with xp_cmdshell procedure, you can [create text files](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-output-to-file-using-sql-server-bcp-command.aspx) from SQL Server database with customized data

For example, following using cursor code you can create text files with sample data in it

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(1000)

DECLARE @name sysname

DECLARE mycursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR SELECT name FROM sys.tables 
OPEN mycursor
FETCH NEXT FROM mycursor INTO @name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

SET @sql = 'bcp "select ''' + replace(@name,'''','''''') + '''" queryout "c:\temp\' + @name + '.txt" -c -UTF8 -T -Slocalhost"'
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @sql

 FETCH NEXT FROM mycursor INTO @name
END

CLOSE mycursor
DEALLOCATE mycursor
```

created files are seen as below

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help.. but don't have execute permission on xp_cmdshell. Will try to get the required permission. Though is there any other work around?